# Views not showing in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a simple App, but I faced the following issue. All of my views have appeared in the preview while designing. However, when I run the APP through my physical device, some of the views disappeared. I'm using a physical device with android update version 8.1.0 since my PC's processor is AMD ryzen I can't use android studio emulator, the target SDK is 26.

please note that all this happened when I updated android studio to 3.5 canary version.

I tried to change the SDK, but I received some errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GPA_4_1">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/FirstCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result_4_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_4_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CreditHour_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SecondCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/FirstCourse"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result_4_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_4_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CreditHour_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ThirdCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SecondCourse"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result_4_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_4_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CreditHour_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ForthCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ThirdCourse"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result_4_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_4_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CreditHour_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/FifthCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ForthCourse"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result_4_5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_4_5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CreditHour_5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SixthCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/FifthCourse"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result_4_6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_4_6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CreditHour_6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SeventhCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SixthCourse"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result_4_7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_4_7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CreditHour_7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/EighthCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SeventhCourse"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Result_4_8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_4_8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CreditHour_8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/EighthCourse"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Calculate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Result">

</Button>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors when they views fail to load or when they disappear? without some type of error the xml isn't going to tell much leave the phone hooked up when your running the app on your physical device and you should get some error when the view fails to show up

Comment: What errors? Please [edit] the question to include the specific errors?

Comment: Which views are not visible in the device?

Comment: the last two views, textview and button

Comment: Do they just not fit onto the visible screen area? It's probably possible to put everything into a `ScrollView`, but I didn't take a closer look at the layout.

Comment: I'll try to the scrollview and will feed you back with the result